# What is the difference between the following sets.

Tags: analysis

What are the following sets and what is the difference between them?

**a)**$f(f^{-1}(a,b))$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = \cos(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$

and

**b)**$f^{-1}(f(a,b))$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = \cos(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$

I feel like the interval is going to be (-1,1), however not sure that for both a) and b).

Please help! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General statements:

$f\left(f^{-1}\left(a,b\right)\right)$ is a subset
of the codomain of $f$:

$$f\left(f^{-1}\left(a,b\right)\right)=\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid x\in f^{-1}\left(a,b\right)\right\} =\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid f\left(x\right)\in\left(a,b\right)\right\} =\left(a,b\right)\cap\text{im}f$$

Note that $f\left(f^{-1}\left(a,b\right)\right)\subseteq\left(a,b\right)$.

---

$f^{-1}\left(f\left(a,b\right)\right)$ is a subset
of the domain of $f$:

$$f^{-1}\left(f\left(a,b\right)\right)=\left\{ x\mid f\left(x\right)\in f\left(a,b\right)\right\} $$

Note that $\left(a,b\right)\subseteq f^{-1}\left(f\left(a,b\right)\right)$

Comment: can you tell what imf is?

Comment: the image of $f$. If $f:A\rightarrow B$ then $\text{im}f=\{f(x)|x\in A\}$.